# displaying the user that owns the notification in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, notifications

i got an application that  includes Activities, Users, Talks and Notifications. the model include

Users Model

```
  has_many :talks, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :notifications, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :activities, :dependent => :destroy
```

Notifications Model

```
 has_many :users, -> {uniq}, through: :talks
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :trackable, polymorphic: true
  has_many :talks
  has_many :notifications
```

When creating a talk i do this

```
def create
    @activity = Activity.find(params[:activity_id])

    @talk = @activity.talks.create!(talk_params)
    @talk.user = current_user
    @talk.save

    #@users= @activity.users.where("id NOT IN (?)", [@activity.user.id, @talk.user])

    @users= User.joins(:talks).where(talks: {id:   @activity.talk_ids}).push(@activity.user).reject {|user| user == @talk.user }.uniq

    ## Lets create a notification for all those who created a comment in this activity
    @users.each do |user|
      Notification.create(activity:@activity, user: user)
    end
    ## Lets create a notification for the owner activity
    #Notification.create(activity:@activity, user: @activity.user)

    redirect_to user_path(current_user)

  end
```

and with this a notification is created what i want is to display the name of the owner of the notification .. i dont know how to go about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
@users.each do |user|
  noti = Notification.create(activity:@activity, user: user)
  notifications = @activity.user.notifications
  notifications << noti
  @activity.user.update(notifications:, notifications)
end
```

If each notification has creator(:user), receiver(:user), so you need to have two columns for Notification model (sender_id, recipient_id).

[Facebook Notification](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/notification/)

You need read about inheritance from single table(User)

[Inheritance from single table(1)](http://www.therailworld.com/posts/18-Single-Table-Inheritance-with-Rails)
[Inheritance from single table(2)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html)

Comment: could you help me with the views too .. will be glad cos right now in my notification controller am doing this in the index action  @notifications = current_user.notifications

Comment: If you want to see notifications of currrent_user,you can write `@notifications = current_user.notifications` in index action

Comment: is there anyway i could do something like notification created by mohammed  how do i go about it in the views